# Why does my query fail when performing json decode search

Tags: mysql, json, angularjs

I've searched already for a couple of hours on this.

When using MYSQL and regular queries I get data back succesfully.

However when I attempt to query using a POST with AngularJS using this code:

```
if($this->get_request_method() != "POST"){
    $this->response('',406);
}

$data = file_get_contents("php://input");

$objData = json_decode($data);

 $response = array();  

 $query='SELECT * FROM faqtbl where issue like "%'.$objData->searchdata.'%"';  <--Fails here!
```

I get the following error:
     **Trying to get property of non-object**

Comment: Why do you think `$objData` is an object?

Comment: Try to use `json_last_error()` to see if there's an error in your json synthax.

Comment: You think that $objData is an object but it's obviously not. Which means that json_decode does not return an object for some reason.

Comment: Also, read this carefully : http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php